# Retain in the same page and do JS operations

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My file structure

```
  front-page
      homepage.html
      lib
        .js
         .php
```

I send the user information to server and doing server side validation. If server side validation fails, i want to load my html page and open log in window if email already exists. I have done the following

```
     if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['email']!='')
    {   
      $email= $_POST['email'];
      $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE emailID = '$email'";
      $result1 = mysqli_query($connection,$sql1) or die("Oops");
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0)
     {
        //echo "This Email is already used.";
        //Write code to go back to register window
        //header('Location: ../homepage.html');
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                console.log("cdsafcds");
                //jQuery.noConflict();
                $(".login_links_login").trigger("click");
                </script>';
     }
    }
```

I don't see any errors and it isnot triggering the click too. I don't have any restrications. Please provide me the best way to do these kinda stuff. I checked with few sites they loads the separate page if php call fails. But i want to know why can't we do it in the same page if so.

HTML:

```
<!----head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-validate.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/homepage.js"> </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/homepage.css" />
</head!--------->

<form method="POST" action="lib/login_validate.php" class="loginDiv right" id="loginForm">
  content goes here
</form>  

Submit click: is handled by jquery
```

Please let me now if any data further needed

Comment: console.log($(".login_links_login").length);
$(".login_links_login").click();

check if the length is > 0 when it consoles it

Comment: yes that s what your code does i guess

Comment: probably that script executes before your jquery is called i mean the script src for jquery is defined

Comment: can you post your homepage.html code i want to see how you have included with the php code

Comment: $(".login_links_login").trigger("click");
I guess your jquery script is load after this line

Comment: post where you have included the jquery file and where you script for click trigger is called

Comment: ok now check if the jquery file is loaded go to view source and click on the src link and see if jquery file gets loaded

Comment: $ says undefined? is that the error?

Comment: Sorry. I don't see any errors now and console.log is also not printed. But i end up with my homepage.html. and click event is also not triggered

Comment: if console is not coming guess your code doesnt enter that echo statement

Comment: But it goes back to html page. How can it skip echo

Comment: check your condition if your echo code is that page and your condition is true it should execute the echo